# How to get hostname from linux kernel module?

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-module, kernel

I think the title is understandable. I can read the procfs file /proc/sys/kernel/hostname, but read files from kernel space is bad idea. Any other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`uname` man page](http://linux.die.net/man/2/uname) says:

> the field `nodename` is meaningless: it gives the name of the present machine in some undefined network, but typically machines are in more than one network and have several names. Moreover, the kernel has no way of knowing about such things, so it has to be told what to answer here.

If you really think you need the host name, use code like this:

```c
#include <linux/utsname.h>

printk("hostname: %s\n", utsname()->nodename);
```